# Strange mysql retrieve with hibernate criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate-criteria

In a web-service i have the following function which retreives some infos of a doctor and his patient based on patient's phone:

```
    public String findDoctorOfPatient(String phone) {
    AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Criteria query = session.createCriteria(doctor.class);
    query.createCriteria("patients", "p");
    query.add(Restrictions.eq("p.phone", phone));
    List<doctor> doctorList = (ArrayList<doctor>) query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    String answear = "";
    for (doctor d : doctorList) {
        answear = answear.concat("docPhone" + d.getPhone() + "docEmail"
                + d.getEmail() + "patDia"
                + d.getPatients().iterator().next().getDiastolic()
                + "patSys"
                + d.getPatients().iterator().next().getSystolic());
    }
    if (doctorList.isEmpty()) {
        session.close();
        factory.close();
        return "No Doctor!";
    } else {
        session.close();
        factory.close();
        return answear;
    }
}
```

The problem is when i have one patient is ok , but when i add second patient it gives me the details of last patient despite i have set to criteria tha firt's patient phone!

I have 2 tables:

1.doctor(id,username,password,phone,email)
2.patient(id,name,surname,phone,systolic,diastolic,doctorid(FK refers to doctor.id))

I have configured properly the hibernate.cfg.xml.

And i have set the class for doctor and patient:

```
@Entity
public class doctor {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = patient.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "doctor")
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<patient> patients = new ArrayList<patient>();

    public Collection<patient> getPatients() {
        return patients;
    }

    public void setPatients(Collection<patient> patients) {
        this.patients = patients;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class patient {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private int systolic;
    private int diastolic;

    @ManyToOne
    private doctor doctor;

    public doctor getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(doctor doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public int getSystolic() {
        return systolic;
    }

    public void setSystolic(int systolic) {
        this.systolic = systolic;
    }

    public int getDiastolic() {
        return diastolic;
    }

    public void setDiastolic(int diastolic) {
        this.diastolic = diastolic;
    }
}
```

[image: doctor]
[image: patient]
[image: patientRelationView![][3]]

In this web-service the response is always the same (given the mobile number) .
It gives me always the patSys=130 and patDia=80 which are the second's patient info!.Something must be wrong in the webservice but to me all seems ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `Criteria` object on `Patient` and no need to obtain `transaction` here.

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Patient.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("phone", phone));

List<Patient> patList = (ArrayList<Patient>) query.list();

String result="";
if(!patList.isEmpty()) {
    Patient patient=patList.get(0);
    result="Doc Phone : " + patient.getDoctor().getPhone();
}
return result;
```

Comment: in my response of web service i have the 1.doctors phone 2.doctors email 3.patientSystolic 4.patientsDiastolic based on patient's phone.Your answear gives only doctor's info.Also what do you exactly do here"Patient patient=doc.patList.get(0);"

Comment: It was typo. You can call other getter methods of patient and doctor too.

Comment: thanks!But can you explain why "session.getTransaction().commit();
" is not necessery?

Comment: @oikonomopo - You should have to use transactions on SELECT statements if you needed to lock the record such that another thread/request would not change the read. But here method returns a string and that's why I said.